# Перенос БД MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Переношу Бд с обычного хостинга на свой vps но при импортре на vps имею следующую ошибку:

```
Вероятно, SQL-запрос содержит ошибку. При наличии таковой, ниже будет выведена ошибка MySQL-сервера, облегчающая диагностику проблемы.

ERROR: Незакрытая кавычка @ 321
STR: '
SQL: 
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'led778_jk3'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_yarpp_related_cache` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping events for database 'led778_jk3'
--

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'led778_jk3'
--


SQL-запрос:

mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'led778_jk3'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548) /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_yarpp_related_cache` ENABLE KEYS */; UNLOCK TABLES; -- -- Dumping events for database 'led778_jk3' -- -- -- Dumping routines for database 'led778_jk3' --

Ответ MySQL: Документация

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'name'': Cann' at line 1
```

Если с конца файла sql удалить строку: 
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'name'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

То все переноситься без проблем
Подскажите как решить проблему, импортирую в mysql 5.5

Все БД уже выкачены в таком виде с сервера так что выкачивать с какими-то параметрами еще раз только на крайний случай

Comment: так вы же решили проблему, удалив строку.

Answer (score 1):

> То все переноси[**тся**](http://tsya.ru/mnemonic.html) без проблем

Не все. Хранимые процедуры не переносятся. Поскольку вместо них в дамп попадает сообщение об ошибке.

> Подскажите как решить проблему

Решать подобного рода проблемы очень просто. Выделяем мышкой сообщение об ошибке ("Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted"), копируем в буфер, вставляем в адресную строку своего браузера, нажимаем Enter, и на открывшейся странице видим десяток ссылок на объяснение и решение данной проблемы. Прочитав рекомендации, применяем их к исходному серверу и запускаем дамп ещё раз.

Answer (score -1):

Раз у вас строка с явным сообщение об ошибке в самом дампе  - значит у вас проблемы с базой из которой этот дамп выгружен. Судя по сообщению повреждена таблица хранящая процедуры в схеме mysql.

Попробуйте выполнить в системе с базой источником команду в консоли:

```
 mysqlrepair -A -uroot -p
```

Для выполнения необходимо знать пароль root сервера mysql
После выполнения repair надо сделать дамп базы заново